# same space retain between three label using autolayot

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6, autolayout

I am learning auto layout from last two days, i have one UITableViewCell xib file and in this cell there is two Labels and one Button, How can i manage Horizontally and vertically space between this subviews of cell?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve ? You haven't given the desired result once the size of the cell changes. Also, what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

This trick is to add empty placeholder `UIView`s between your labels/buttons and bind them with an Equal Width constraint.

Following images show how it is done for horizontal spacing. Purple colored views are the placeholder `UIView`s. You can later set their `alpha=0` or make them hidden so they will not appear when the app is running.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you need the placeholder view ? Can you not achieve the exact same thing without it ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way to achieve this using Auto Layout. I used this same method (placing spacer views in between) with old HTML layouts as well. I hate the cluttered view hierarchy too :(